# Spring 3 Form Validation link to JPA Entity

Tags: spring, jpa, validation

I am planning to use Spring 3 validations in my Web Application. I was considering that since I already have the properties of my JPA entities annotated with some standard validations like nullable="false" or length="50". Is there any way I could reuse JPA validations in Spring 3 Backing forms?

I feel a better idea would be to recode the validations on the Spring form as we can have more helpful error messages. What do you think -
Is it possible in a clean way to reuse JPA validations in Spring forms?
What is a better design - reimplement the validations or reuse the basic ones and code more specific validations separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, as soon as you write a custom `Validator` you're responsible for validating all fields regarding Spring's `WebDataBinder`. Validation constraint annotations still throw exceptions though if violated.

Comment: yeah i agree that the validations will fail at the JPA layer, but I will have to code the error messages again. It would have been nicer if I could have done something like django's ModelForm which inherits the validations from the model layer.

Comment: Adding simple rules in your custom validator is quite easy, like `ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "field", "field_required");` with the added benefit of internationalizable error codes.